# conditional expectation against finite sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a bounded random variable. Suppose $|X|\le 1$. Divide $[-1,1]$ into $k$ many disjoint equal-length intervals of length $\frac{2}{k}$, $I_1:=[-1,-1+\frac{2}{k}),\dots I_k:=[1-\frac{2}{k},1]$. Let $F_1, F_2, \cdots, F_k$ denote the inverse images of thoes intervals under $X$. Let $\mathscr{F}=\sigma(F_1, F_2, \cdots, F_k)$ denote the sigma algebra generated by those inverse images. I wonder if the following claim is true:

> claim: Almost surely, $X$ and $\mathbb E(X|\mathscr{F})$ take value in the same subinterval $I_n$ as defined above (and as a result $|X-\mathbb E(X|\mathscr{F})|\le \frac{2}{k}$ almost surely).

This is intuitively true to me, since the sigma algebra $\mathscr{F}$ gives the information on thoes $k$ places where the values of $X$ could lie. But how to prove this rigorously?

Comment: Can you verify that $$\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathscr{F}]=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{E}[X\mid F_i] \mathbf{1}_{F_i} \qquad \mathbb{P}\text{-a.s.}$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Sorry I don't know this, any hint?

Comment: Note that any $\mathscr{F}$-measurable random variable $Y$ can be written in the form $$Y=\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i \mathbf{1}_{F_i}$$ for some constants $a_1,\ldots,a_k$. (To see this, note first that each $\mathscr{F}$-measurable event is the union of some subfamily of $\{F_1,\ldots,F_k\}$. Then the same is true for each $\{Y=c\}$, and this immediately leads to the above formula.) Now let $Y=\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathscr{F}]$ and determine the values of $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ by using the definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: @SangchulLee sorry I still don't know how to verify my claim after establishing the identity you suggested...

Comment: Recall that $Y=\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathscr{F}]$ is any $\mathscr{F}$-measurable function characterized by the property that $$\mathbb{E}[Y\mathbf{1}_F]=\mathbb{E}[X\mathbf{1}_F]\qquad\text{for all} \quad F \in \mathscr{F}.$$ Now apply this with $F = F_i$ for each $i=1,\ldots,k$.